# Lets do something with "Set up dual monitor" post!

Tags: discussion, duplicates, cleanup, canonical-questions

After read [this post](https://askubuntu.com/q/334605/62483) I though *"I'll find the dupe and done"* but after [search for a dupe](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=how+to+set+up+dual+monitors) about *"How to set up dual monitor?"* I didn't find any question with acceptable answers.

There are a lot of questions without answers, responses from the OP or any activity since months.

I'd only found this useful *two* post:

- [How can I set up dual monitor display with ATI driver?](https://askubuntu.com/q/71457/62483)
- [How can I set up dual monitors with nVidia?](https://askubuntu.com/q/84181/62483)

*Maybe* we can use both post as *canonical posts*. The first one for **ATI** and the second for **nVidia**.

Are both post acceptable?
Are they *up-to-date*?
Do we need better answers?
Do you know another post that can be used to link dupes?

Comment: We need one for Intel as well, which is basically just opening up Displays and clicking the buttons.

Comment: Agree. I just mentioned the two majors firms, but there are other brands too.

Comment: When you say *dual monitors* you mean, mirroring or expanding? or both?

Comment: BTW, I said the same thing and ended with the same results.

Comment: I mean, plug two devices and work with both. There aren't many differences..

Comment: Pick the three questions for each video card and post it as an answer then we can get to work!

Comment: And then we need one for Optimus!

Comment: @JorgeCastro That is what I'm waiting for. I think that both mentioned questions are for ATI and nVidia. What other could be for Intel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## ATI

For ATI hardware we should use [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/71457/62483) as the *canonical* post.

## nVidia

For nVidia hardware we should use [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/84181/62483) as the *canonical* post.

---

In both post we need users confirming if *the methods mentioned there will work for newer versions of Ubuntu or not*.